# Microsoft Graph filter group members where accountEnabled eq true

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

When querying Microsoft Graph to return all members in a group, how can you filter the accountEnabled property via C#?

I can send this query via graph explorer and the results are returned as expected:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{03c3ed49-6ee3-43ca-b189-3a73f73c96a1}/members?$filter=accountEnabled eq true&$count=true`

Funny thing is if you take off `&$count=true` the query fails. Not sure why adding the count makes the query including the `accountEnabled` filter work.

My query in C# is:

```
var query = await _client.Groups["{group-id-here}"].Members
                .Request()
                .Filter("accountEnabled eq true")
                .GetAsync();
```

But it fails with `ServiceException: Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery Message: The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$count` query option to the request.

```
var queryOptions = new List<Option>()
            {
                new QueryOption("$count", "true")
            };

var query = await _client.Groups["{group-id-here}"].Members
                .Request(queryOptions)
                .Filter("accountEnabled eq true")
                .GetAsync();
```